# How do I save a customized AWS EC2 image (AMI)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

So, I am using an ubuntu AMI (amazon machine image). I have installed a couple of compiler, softwares, packages etc on this image. Now I want to save this image; so that I can use it to spawn multiple identical instances of this same AMI. How can I save my create and image of my current AMI instance in order to replicate it to create multiple identical instances?

Comment: To be clear, you aren't using an AMI, you are using an EC2 instance that was created from an AMI. An AMI is a snapshot in time, not a running server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a new AMI Image

1. Go to the AWS console
2. go to your EC2 dashboard : in the instances list
3. select your instance, right click on your instance
4. select image / create image

This will create an AMI image that you can reuse later

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks :)